# How to drag interface from two classes?

Tags: php

I have a anonimous function `login` which has `$headers` argument. I use `new Headers()` if code is generative and `new TestHeaders()` if I test code. My problem is that `$headers` argument has not type hint. This argument is `Headers` or `TestHeaders`. So I should drag interface from `Headers` and `TestHeaders` and use that as type hint. My question is how can I drag interface with this two classes ?

```
class TestHeaders
{
    public function profile(int $userId): TestHeader
    {
        return new TestHeader();
    }
}
```

```
class Headers
{

    public function profile(string $header): Header
    {
        return Header::profile($header);
    }
}
```

```
$login = function ($headers) {
    $getView = function ($headers): View {
        example code
    };

    $view = $getView ($headers);
    $view->render();
};
$login (new Headers());
```

I do that, but how I can add metohd profile from TestHeaders to interface ? There methods have the same name.

```js
interface HeadersInterface
{
    public function profile(string $header): Header;

}

$login = function (HeadersInterface $headers, $session) {
   
    $getView = function ($headers): View {
        example code
    };

    $view = $getView($headers);
    $view->render();
};
$login (new Headers());
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why don't you simply implement an interface that is implemented by both classes? Or is the _actual_ question something else, like what return type the `profile()` methods should have?

Comment: @arkascha How can I do implements interface that implemented by both classes ? Could you show me example ?

Comment: @juros22 `class TestHeaders implements YourInterface` ?

Comment: @nice_dev I make interface but how can I do add method from `TestHeaders` to interface ? There methods are the same name `profile` Show me code in post.

Answer (score 0):

An interface describes a **contract** listing all the things that are **the same for all implementing classes**. The interface definition should answer the question "if I have an instance of `HeadersInterface`, what guarantees are there about what I can do with it?" Generally, this consists of a list of methods, with promises about their input and output types.

An interface doesn't have to describe *all* the methods of a class - a class might implement multiple interfaces for use in different contexts, or have some additional functionality that's unique to that class.

If we look at your example, there is only one method we could include, but **there is no promise we can make about it**:

```
function test(HeadersInterface $headers) {
    $headers->profile(42); // error if $headers is a Headers instance
    $headers->profile('hello'); // error if $headers is a TestHeaders instance
}
```

So the list of functions we can include in our interface is empty; our interface will just look like this:

```
interface HeadersInterface {
}
```

In a language where interfaces must be marked explicitly, like PHP, such an interface might still be useful: it tells you that this object is *intended* for use in a particular context. However, it does mean you can't actually do anything with an object if all you know is that it implements that interface.

To be more useful, you need to decide what the contract is for *all* Headers classes, and change the implementations to match. That means:

- They all accept the same inputs - they can accept *additional* inputs, but they must not reject an input that the interface promises will be accepted
- They all return *compatible* values - they can be more *specific* in what they return, but it must be a *sub-type* of what the interface promises

For instance, the following would be valid:

```
interface HeaderInterface { /* ... */ }
class Header implements HeaderInterface { /* ... */ }
class TestHeader implements HeaderInterface { /* ... */ }

interface HeadersInterface
{
    public function profile(string $header): HeaderInterface;
}

class Headers implements HeadersInterface
{
    // return type is allowed because Header is sub-type of HeaderInterface
    public function profile(string $header): Header
    {
        return Header::profile($header);
    }
}

class TestHeaders implements HeadersInterface
{
    // accepts int *in addition to* the string which the interface promises
    // return type is allowed because TestHeader is sub-type of HeaderInterface
    public function profile(string|int $headerOrUserId): TestHeader
    {
        return new TestHeader();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this link have been enough to answer the question? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php